# RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders vs $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']

Tags: angularjs, restangular, doorkeeper

Is there really any difference between the **RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders** and **$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']** setters?

I got a AngularJS app that communicates with a Rails app that uses https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper. I'm setting the Athorization header when the users has logged in.
Any reason to pick one over the other?  :-)

--
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders` will work for requests made via Restangular only.

While `$http.defaults.headers.common` will work on all requests made via `$http` including Restangular requests, because Restangular also use `$http` behind the scene.